# Changing the route from posts/article to blog/article in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, namespaces, scope

I'm in trouble with routes in Rails. I've been trying to get a path like: home/blog/title-article but the closes I get is: home/blog/**posts**/title-article

I've tried with namespace, scope and one by one with get 'blog' => 'posts#blablabla', but I get errors like UrlGenerationError or NameError every time I change the paths. I've read the official guide and some answers in this forum, but I'm getting more confused hehe

In my last try I generated a controller Blog and a scaffold Post. The output of rake routes is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdfPc.png

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope :blog do
    resources :posts
  end

  get 'blog' => 'blog#index'

  root 'pages#index'
```

...

Thank you!

Now my routes are like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKsFG.png 
 Thank you!

Comment: The problem is your scope.  You are telling rails that you want routes like `/blog/post/xxx`.  If you want RESTful routes for `blog`, use `resources :blog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure its what you expect but try:

```
resources :posts, path: 'blog'
```

Feels weird though.

Btw, I guess you have the errors due to url helpers.

use `rake routes` to check the existing routes and the related url helpers.

[Doc lives here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: I am thinking that he meant that /home is the base URL as there are no mentions of a home resource.

Comment: Yep! It works... I guess it wasn't my last try hehehe.resources :posts, path: 'blog'